# Xamarin Android - Call API using HttpClient with Certificate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We're trying to communicate with an API of ours which needs a certificate in the request but it doesn't work well.

Usually we used an external service or an Azure API Management API just by passing a SubscriptionKey in the request headers, but this time we have a certificate (.cer) that we need to inject in the AndroidHttpClientHandler but this feature doesn't seem to be supported, or maybe we're using it wrong ?

Do you know if this scenario is truly possible and if yes, how we should achieve it ? I tried many things such as create a custom AndroidHttpClientHandler to allow putting a ClientCertificate in it but without success

Comment: Do you used public certificate or private certificate(self-certificate)?If you used the private certifcates, you will meet `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate exception.`I do not know which specific features did you want to acheved, If you want to connect server by SSL, it could be acheved.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/securing-web-requests-with-tls-1-2/

Comment: Well what we tried so far didn't work because when we wanted to use the classic WebRequestHandler it didn't work because an exception was thrown "NotImplementedException" --> our project is still a PCL (targeting .NET 4.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to get it work :D For those who are interested, here's how I achieve it :

**TL;DR: Upgrade to Visual Studio 2019 and HttpWebRequest comes to the rescue (you can find the code sample below) ;-)**

Context: our project consists of a PCL and a Android project. In the team, we know we have to migrate the PCL to a .NET Standard project but it takes time, especially when you have a lot of librairies to deal with (libraries that are not updated to .NET Standard) xP

- When you want to call an API, the first thing that comes to your mind is to use the HttpClient/HttpRequestHandler pair where we just have to pass our certificate in the HttpRequestHandler as follows :

  httpRequestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(..))

Why it didn't work ? Because we're developing with Xamarin.Android which uses under the hood Mono.Droid, therefore we're meeting the unpopular NotImplementedException() ! What about WebRequestHandler ? Well the same fate :P

Hopefully the salvation came from HttpWebRequest as follows :

```
        private Task<string> ExecuteRequest(Uri uri, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            // Create a web request that points to our secured Backend API
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

            if (certificate != null)
            {
                // Associate the certificates with the request
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            }

            // Launch the web request
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Output the stream to a jsonTextReader or anything else depending on your needs
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                // Do whatever you want
            }
        }
```

This code worked on my machine (Visual Studio 2019) but not on my colleague (Visual Studio 2017) : indeed the following exception was met :

> **System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception**.

I also have VS2017 installed on my machine so I've tried to execute the same code with it and as strange as it sounds, I also got the error

Et voilà :) Of course, the certificate had to be "an Embedded resource"